# How to access numpad keys in XMonad?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xmonad

I want to map some programs to the ten numbers of the numpad, which should start when I press mod4Mask + a number.

I know that ordinary numbers are accessed with xK_1, xK_2,... but what about the numpad numbers?

And will it make a difference if numlock is activated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Xmonad/Key codes](https://wiki.haskell.org/Xmonad/Key_codes),

> You can also search in `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h` and lower-case the first character (**`XK*`** becomes **`xK*`**).

Usually (some keyboard configurations differ), the large editing keypad sends symbols such as `XK_KP_0`, etc., (the symbols with `_KP_`), and pressing *NumLock* makes the keys send the alternate symbol (such as `XK_0`) which is printed on the keyboard.

xterm, for instance, uses that mapping of `XK_KP_xxx` to determine what escape sequences to send (this is taken for granted in *[Why doesn't my keypad work?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_keypad)* in the XTerm FAQ).